# RN4678 Does Not Enter Command Mode

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, microchip, bluetooth-low-energy

I've been trying to get the Microchip RN4678 bluetooth module working so I can start having fun with it, but I'm having very very limited success. The problem is the fact that the datasheet states:

> To enter Command mode, type $$$ into the terminal emulator. Once RN4678 enters
> Command mode, it sends the string CMD via the UART to indicate the start of Command
> mode session.

I'm doing exactly that, along with every variation and am getting no response. Here's my setup. First things first I've got it plugged into a breadboard like this:

[image]

I'm using a stock TTL programmer based around the FTDI232R, and it's all being controlled and monitored from the OSX program [Serial.](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/) Here's the settings I'm using in serial.

[image]

**Observations from my troubleshooting so far:**

1. The chip itself is working fine. I can connect to it through the
   mBIoT utility iPhone app, and it sends and transmits data from phone to computer and vice versa fine, so I know the module isn't dead.
2. The modules CTS pin doesn't get pulled low unless there is a paired connection. When my phone is connected I can pipe data through the RN4678 from computer to phone with hardware flow enabled just fine, but as soon as I disconnect my phone, I cannot talk to the module at all.
3. I've looked into the option of the modules "fast-mode" being activated by default, where the original "$$$" command doesn't work, and instead you have to pull a specific pin low. So I went around, and pulled each pin low individually and had no success.

Right now it just feels like theres a hidden pin in there that needs to be pulled in some sort of direction. I've had a good look at the Pictail Reference design for this module and I'm faily sure I haven't missed any pins.

If this is ringing any bells for anyone, or if you have any ideas I should try I'd really love your help. Here's the corresponding [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN4678-Bluetooth-Dual-Mode-Module-Data-Sheet-DS50002519D.pdf) and [User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002506B.pdf) for this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with RN4870 and it worked just fine for me after 2 months of debugging. It just takes time. When I did it, I didn't connect CTS or any other pin. I just had Vbat to 3.3V, Gnd, tx and rx. Rst is internally pulled high. Don't mess with it.

I see that you are sending 'LF' after your command. When sending that command you should not send LF or CR. The chip doesn't interpret it as a command for data mode. Deselect LF and try sending $$$. I had this problem when I was working on this. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I've followed your advice, now I'm getting a reply! But it's just a random character. With the recommended settings it looks like a "<tab>r"

Comment: Ok, so I found out if I slow the baud rate right down I can get the sent string returned back to me. From 4800 onwards, the string starts corrupting on return, all the way till 115200, where the string is completely ruined.

Comment: What is the baud rate that you are using? The default baud rate is 115200. You should set the baud rate to 115200. Now send $$$ without LF or CR. what is the exact response that you are getting? it should be "cmd"

If you want echo, send '+' after setting the chip in command mode. Can you share the screenshot of your serial terminal? I can understand better.

Comment: I’m sorry to say I ended up switching to the RN4871 and it’s working so good. I think I may have fried my RN4678’s, but when I tried your advice I definitely started getting a response but it was garbled as. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worried .. Glad to be of help. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

P2_0 and P2_4 should be pulled high as you have in your schematic (but not necessary as the datasheet claims there are internal pull-ups), but the EAN pin (#20) needs to be pulled to GND for "Normal Operation / Application Mode". Refer to Table 2-1 in the datasheet. Your configuration where all lines are pulled high is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual the pin "SW_BTN" doesn't has to be connected and is stated "default: disabled". But in reality this input has to be set to BAT_IN (3,3V) permanentely if the module should work!!
As stated above the EAN Pin has to be pulled to GND to enable "normal operating mode / command mode". The configuration in the following modified drawing is working fine (without the option to flash new firmware - in this case the signals P2_0, P2_4 & EAN need another signal configuration).
[image]
Afterwards the module (RN4678) is running in "normal communication mode" but can be switched to command mode by sending "§§§CR" (CR = one sign) answered by "CMD> CRLF" (CRLF = two signs) and so on ...